# Eclipse Throwing IOException when trying to open port

Tags: java, eclipse, serversocket

Whenever I call `new ServerSocket(8080);` I get an IOException in Eclipse.  How can I stop this?  It works fine if I run the program from the command line, but it is rather annoying that I am using Eclipse as an IDE but I can't run my program from it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably eclipse is using `8080` port by default to host your web application.

Try to change the port in `server.xml` from 8080 to anything else( lets say `9000`).This should work for you.